# Solving the Stochastic Differential Equation $dX_t = a X_t dt + \sigma d W_t$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

> Consider the Stochastic Differential Equation $dX_t = a X_t dt + \sigma d W_t$ for $t \geq 0$, where $a,\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $W$ denotes a Brownian Motion.
>
> I want to find a solution of this.
>
> As a hint I am asked to consider the ansatz $X_t = C_t e^{at}$, where (I think) $C_t = g(W_t)$ for some function $g$.

I think I need to use Ito's formula on $f:(t,W_t) \mapsto g(W_t) e^{at}$. Using that $\langle Id,Id\rangle_t = 0, \langle Id,W\rangle_t =0$ and $\langle W,W\rangle_t = t $, Ito's formula for this in the two dimensional case yields that
$$
g(W_t)e^{at} = g(W_0) + a\int_0^t g(W_s) e^{as}ds + \int_0^t g'(W_s) e^{as}dW_s +\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t g''(W_s) e^{as} ds
$$
The $g(W_0)$ term doesn't matter and as for the second term this already looks good for the equation. Hence we have to figure out how
$$
\int_0^t g'(W_s) e^{as}dW_s +\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t g''(W_s) e^{as} ds \overset{!}{=}\int_0^t \sigma d W_s = \sigma W_t
$$
I can't see how to make equal this constant $\sigma$. Do we want something like $g(t)=\sigma W_t$ with second derivative 0?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, $C_t$ does not only depend on the point-value of $W_t$, but on the full path from $0$ to $t$. Use the Ito formula for $C_t=f(t,X_t)=e^{-at}X_t$ to get
$$
dC_t=f_t\,dt+f_x\,dX_t+\frac12f_{xx}d⟨X⟩_t
\\=-ae^{-at}X_t\,dt+e^{-at}(aX_t\,dt+σdW_t)+0
=σe^{-at}dW_t
$$
Thus
$$
C_t=C_0+\int_0^tσe^{-as}dW_s
$$

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you for your answer! There are a few points I am unsure about still. The way you sort of "plug-in" the differential equation, is this valid? It has to make sense a stochastic integrals which I know are born linear so I guess it holds because of this? Also, now you have obtained an expression for $C_t$ but we need one for $X_t$. Is this then simply
$X_t = e^{at}C_t = e^{at}C_0 + \int_0^t \sigma e^{-a(s-t)} dW_s$? But then there is no true starting value because $ e^{at}C_0$ depends on $t$? Isn't this a problem?

Comment: Yes, that is the general Ito formula. Yes to the reconstruction, and $C_0=X_0$.